# Retrieving next xml node by previous node's value - using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml:

```
<century>  
 <question>What is silvia</question>  
 <answer>silvia is artificial intelligence</answer>  
 <question>What is your name</question> 
  <answer>my name is RAMESH</answer> 
</century>
```

I would like to get an answer based on a given question using linq. How should I do that?

Current code:

```
string textToSearch = "When did AI research start"; 
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\SILVIA\New task\FinalXml.xml"); 

var q = doc.Descendants("CenturySoft")
           .Descendants("question")
           .Where(item => item.Value == textToSearch)
           .Select(item => item.NextNode)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm getting output with the `<answer>` tag. How to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing so is with Linq to Xml:

```
var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml")
         .Descendants("century")
         .SelectMany(element => element.Descendants("question")
                                       .Zip(element.Descendants("answer"),
                                            (q,a) => new { 
                                                Question = q.Value, 
                                                Answer = a.Value 
                                            }))
         .ToList();
```

*Note that this will not work well if you have more than one answer for a question or if you have a problem in the ordering of question, answer*

Another way of doing it (using the `XPathSelectElement` extension method - add `using System.Xml.XPath`) is:

```
var question = "What is silvia";

var answer = XDocument.Load("data.xml")
                      .XPathSelectElement($"century/question[\"{question}\"]")
                      .NextNode;
```

---

Following your update, you can do:

```
var q = doc.Descendants("century")
           .Descendants("question")
           .Where(item => item.Value == textToSearch)
           .Select(item => item.ElementsAfterSelf().FirstOrDefault())
           .FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

When using `NextNode` you get an [`XNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode(v=vs.110).aspx) instance which is a more difficult to use class so instead you can do like in the above.

Comment: No not solved. i have linq query like this   string textToSearch = "When did AI research start";                 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\SILVIA\New task\FinalXml.xml");  var q = doc.Descendants("CenturySoft").Descendants("question")
                .Where(item => item.Value == textToSearch)
                .Select(item => item.NextNode)
                .FirstOrDefault();  in this i am getting output as   <answer>I think yes, but we aren't yet at a level of AI at which this process can begin.</answer>. i want output as without answer tag. please provide any solution. thank you.

Comment: @BhimanaRamesh - Please if you may delete your comment with the code and if you may upvote and accept my answer I will be very greatful

Answer (score 0):

This will only work so long as there are ordered pairs of q's and a's

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    'to load from a file
    '  xe = XElement.Load("Your Path Here")

    ' for testing
    xe = <century>
             <question>What is silvia</question>
             <answer>silvia is artificial intelligence</answer>
             <question>What is your name</question>
             <answer>my name is RAMESH</answer>
         </century>

    Dim qs As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xe...<question>
    Dim ans As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xe...<answer>


    For x As Integer = 0 To qs.Count - 1
        Debug.WriteLine("Q: {0}?  A: {1}", qs(x).Value, ans(x).Value)
    Next
```

If the XML had a different structure (better?) this would be easier.

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    xe = <QandA>
             <item>
                 <question>What is silvia</question>
                 <answer>silvia is artificial intelligence</answer>
             </item>
             <item>
                 <question>What is your name</question>
                 <answer>my name is RAMESH</answer>
             </item>
         </QandA>
```